# Why my onclick function in button that is echo by php cannot work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, echo

I do not know why this cannot work. It can output a button element but the onclick function cannot work at all. Not even an alert box pop up. PLS help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    
    <?php $name = "John"; 
    echo "<button type='button' onclick='callYou('".$name."')'> click me </button>";
    ?>
    
    <script>
      function callYou(name) {
          if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
             $greeting = "hello"+name;
             echo $greeting;
          } else {
             echo "nothing";
          }
      }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have quoting issues. Have you looked at your page source to see what it actually generated? And also make sure you check the developer toolbar console, it will tell you about your syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes in the code, try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


    <?php
    $name = 'John';
    echo '<button type="button" onclick="callYou(\'' . $name . '\')"> click me </button>';
    ?>
    
    <script>
        function callYou(name) {
            if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                var greeting = "hello" + name;
                alert(greeting)
            } else {
                alert("nothing")
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Go and do some reading about PHP, JavaScript syntax!